# Translating "The process may take several minutes." into Mexican Spanish

Tags: traducción, méxico, hispanoamérica

I've generated the following translations for these two sentences, but they don't quite sound right to me. I'd like some feedback!

> After the pink progress bar disappears, you must restart the device to complete the upgrade.

Translation:

> Después de desaparecer la barra de progreso de color rosa, reinicie el dispositivo para completar la actualización.

---

> The process may take several minutes.

Translation:

> El proceso puede durar varios minutos.

I don't want the text to sound too robotic or formal. How would this sound in conversational Mexican Spanish?

Comment: Hello Tim and welcome to [spanish.se]. As is now, the question is a bit off topic, since it is **asking for corrections in a text**. Check [ask] and [tour]. Then, [edit] the post to provide specific questions on specific topics so we will be able to assist you.

Comment: I actually think that each sentence should be asked in a separate question. They might be related, but they are different. Also, the title should be edited to summarize the question. If you were searching for previous questions, would you be abla to know what the question is about? Like 1: "how to translate 'The process may take several minutes.' " and " how to reanslate 'After the pink progress bar disappears' into Mexican Spanish".

Answer (score 1):

For this:

> After the pink progress bar disappears, you must restart the device to complete the upgrade.

I'd say something like this:

> Después de que la barra de progreso rosa desaparezca, debe reiniciar el dispositivo para completar la actualización

For this:

> The process may take several minutes.

I'd say something like this:

> El proceso puede tardar varios minutos.

For me, it's a little formal, and informal at the same time, yo can see the translation covering both sides.